# How do I call A np.zeros of integers?

Tags: python

```
Musica = np.zeros((row*120,3))

for k in range(21, 90):
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(Max[k], Min[k]):
            Musica[i*120 + j,:] = 0,i,j
            if np.all(data[i*col + j,:]==(255.000,0.000,0.000,i,j)):
                Music[i*120 + j,:] = 1,i,j
```

`Max[k]` and `Min[k]` are number that belong to the mathematical interger group, but I get this message from python

> "TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got numpy.float64."

How do I call a `np.zeros` of the integer type ?

Right now I am trying to use the fallowing code:

```
Musica = np.zeros((row*120,3))

for k in range(21, 90):
    for i in range(row):
        Max = int(Max[k])
        Min = int(Min[k])
        for j in range(Max, Min):
            Musica[i*120 + j,:] = 0,i,j
            if np.all(data[i*col + j,:]==(255.000,0.000,0.000,i,j)):
                Musica[i*120 + j,:] = 1,i,j
```

And the error message I am receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-115-4aef2441146c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Arthur_USP/Desktop/Informação/Nova abordagem/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Arthur_USP/Desktop/Informação/Nova abordagem')

  File "C:\Users\Arthur_USP\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Arthur_USP\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Arthur_USP/Desktop/Informação/Nova abordagem/untitled0.py", line 181, in <module>

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Where line 181 is "Max = int(Max[k])"

Comment: What's `row`? Also, post the complete error message, including stack trace.

Comment: row is the size of pixels in the width of a image.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could try `np.zeros(shape).astype(int)`.

EDIT:
Actually, zeros accepts the dtype argument. So even better is `np.zeros(shape, dtype=int)`